# How to return to the login page in VCL for the web/Intraweb?

Tags: delphi, nginx, logout, intraweb

I have an application built with Delphi 10 / VCL for the web - Intraweb 14.2.7.

I implemented the Logout feature that basically does this:

```
// Appurl := WebApplication.ApplicationURL;
WebApplication.TerminateAndRedirect(Appurl+'/$/');
```

This works in most cases, but when the app runs behind a reverse Proxy (I use [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/)) `WebApplication.ApplicationURL` is not as I expect.

From localhost my app runs at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/$/`
and in localhost `WebApplication.ApplicationURL` is `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

while using reverse proxy (so accessing from any other machine)
the app is reachable at `https://myapp.mycompany.com/$/`
and in this case `WebApplication.ApplicationURL` is `http://myapp.mycompany.com:8000` therefore on logout the app redirects the browser to `http://myapp.mycompany.com:8000/$/` that does not exist.

Probably by fine-tuning NGINX it is possible to find a workaround anyway I would like to ask whether Intraweb has a built in system to go back to the main URL.

Comment: Use a relative redirect not absolute so just `'/$/'` instead of `Appurl+'/$/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment you can try to use `WebApplication.TerminateAndRedirect('/$/');` avoiding the absolute address